# Implement the member predicate as a one-liner

Tags: list, prolog, dcg

Interview question!

This is how you normally define the `member` relation in Prolog:

```
member(X, [X|_]).        % member(X, [Head|Tail]) is true if X = Head 
                         % that is, if X is the head of the list
member(X, [_|Tail]) :-   % or if X is a member of Tail,
  member(X, Tail).       % ie. if member(X, Tail) is true.
```

Define it using only one rule.

Comment: Interview  for a job? what job? where? do people get jobs thanks to Prolog?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

1. Solution:

   ```
   member(X, [Y|T]) :- X = Y; member(X, T).
   ```
2. Demonstration:

   ```
   ?- member(a, []).
   fail.
   ?- member(a, [a]).
   true ;
   fail.
   ?- member(a, [b]).
   fail.
   ?- member(a, [1, 2, 3, a, 5, 6, a]).
   true ;
   true ;
   fail.
   ```
3. How it works:

   - We are looking for an occurrence of the first argument, `X`, in the the second argument, `[Y|T]`.
   - The second argument is assumed to be a list. `Y` matches its head, `T` matches the tail.
   - As a result the predicate fails for the empty list (as it should).
   - If `X = Y` (i.e. `X` can be unified with `Y`) then we found `X` in the list. Otherwise (`;`) we test whether `X` is in the tail.
4. Remarks:

   - Thanks to [humble coffee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77533/humble-coffee) for pointing out that using `=` (unification) yields more flexible code than using `==` (testing for equality).
   - This code can also be used to enumerate the elements of a given list:

     ```
     ?- member(X, [a, b]).
     X = a ;
     X = b ;
     fail.
     ```
   - And it can be used to "enumerate" all lists which contain a given element:

     ```
     ?- member(a, X).
     X = [a|_G246] ;
     X = [_G245, a|_G249] ;
     X = [_G245, _G248, a|_G252] ;
     ...
     ```
   - Replacing `=` by `==` in the above code makes it a lot less flexible: it would immediately fail on `member(X, [a])` and cause a stack overflow on `member(a, X)` (tested with SWI-Prolog version 5.6.57).

Comment: hmm very cute. The key was the ; operator - I didn't know you could do 'or's inside of a rule.

Comment: If you replace "X == Y" with "X = Y", then you can do member(X, [a]). and even get a sensible result for member(a, X).

Comment: @humble coffee: thanks! I barely touched Prolog the last few years, so my knowledge is a bit rusty :)

Comment: It being used to enumerate elements / lists etc. is an awesome side-effect of the way prolog works =). not special to this example - if you define Addition, you automatically get Subtraction. If you define a TypeChecker, you also define an enumerator for all well-typed programs.

Comment: the point of X == Y vs X = Y is that with the second one you're forcing unification (bad as far i can tell), with the second one you do a deep equality check

Answer (score 23):

Since you didn't specify what other predicates we're allowed to use, I'm going to try and cheat a bit. `:P`

```
member(X, L) :- append(_, [X|_], L).
```

Answer (score 7):

```
newmember(X, Xs) :-
   phrase(( ..., [X] ),Xs, _).
```

With

```
... --> [] | [_], ... .
```

Actually, the following definition also ensures that `Xs` is a list:

```
member_oflist(X, Xs) :-
   phrase(( ..., [X], ... ), Xs).
```

#### Acknowledgements

The first appearance of above definition of `... //0` is on p. 205, Note 1 of

> David B. Searls, Investigating the Linguistics of DNA with Definite Clause Grammars.  NACLP 1989, Volume 1.

Answer (score -3):

You can also try this:

```
member(X,L) :- append(_,[X|_],L).
```

Comment: Oops, I haven't noticed that this solution already had been given.